# Default selected value in select box is not working in angularjs if the value is fetching from json

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I am new in angularjs. Currently I am working on select box in angularjs. I need to show select box with database values and with default selected values.For me values are coming in drop down but initial selection is not working.

Here is my code Any answer or suggestions is highly appreciated

html

```
<body ng-controller='CompositionController'>
<input type="hidden" name="selectedRegion" id="selectedRegion" value="14" />
<label class="popupboxtext">Select Substrate</label>
                                        <select class="popupselect" ng-options="sb.SUBSTRATE_ID as sb.SUBSTRATE_NAME for sb in Substrate" ng-model="selectedSubstrate" >
                                          <option value="" >Select Substrate</option>
                                        </select><br/>

<label class="popupboxtext">Coating Side 1</label>                                  
                                       <select class="popupselect" ng-options="CS1.COATING_ID as CS1.COATING_NAME for CS1 in CoatingS1" ng-model='selectedCoatingS1'>
                                            <option value="" >Select Coating</option>
                                        </select>
</body>
```

js file

```
$scope.selectedCoatingS1 = invalue;
```

here this 'invalue' I am fetching from database. Here i am having the problem

```
$scope.selectedCoatingS1 = '29';
```

Here is the link you can check this for further details 
http://54.148.151.90/test

if i am giving direct value with cots then its working perfectly but with database value its not working . Any suggestions are highly appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: try to use console.log(invalue) just before $scope.selectedCoating = invalue; and check is it consisting any value.

Comment: i already printing that you can see in console invaue29

Comment: Please update question there is typo $scope.selectedCoating should be $scope.selectedCoatingS1

Comment: its my mistake while writing here

Comment: How you are parsing json ?

Comment: http://54.148.151.90/jsonapi/getDefaultValues/14

Answer (score 0):

In angular the select controls works with objects so instead of setting a string ('29') to the scope... try setting the whole object, something like:

```
$scope.selectedCoatingS1=$scope.CoatingS1[0];
```

Where defaultCoat should be something like:

```
{
  COATING_ID:'someId',
  COATING_PROR1:'some property,
  ...
}
```

Comment: But in json I am getting like this "Glazing":[
{
"COATING_1_ID":"29",
"SUBSTRATE_1_ID":"3",
"THICKNESS_1_ID":"5",
"COATING_2_ID":"-1"
}
],  these are the default values

Comment: Let me review your source code, could you put in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/athisandy/zte8qxgz/ here is the jsfiddle .but its not working

Comment: you cant call from a different domain using ajax, just simulate in jsfiddle. do another thing, copy in your question the json with the coat results please and let me know which var is storing this results.

Comment: Try selecting the first result of this array, something like $scope.selectedCoatingS1=coatResults[0];

Comment: and values are fetching from database how i can do this in fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70848/discussion-between-carlos-verdes-and-athi).

Comment: Select Substrate is loading properly with default vale same way only i am doing for coating

Comment: I think u havent understand my question